# Flutter routing with Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, routes

I'm totally new to Flutter and just started my own project. I am currently stuck with routing and trying to explain my problem.
I have a database in Firestore with 3 different countries each country has 3 cities and each city has its own image and description.
So the question is how to create dynamic routing, for example, write code that looks at which country I choose and upload that country's cities on the next page?
I added an image of how should look for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the nested Firebase database. Like this [Firebase-storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4HWg.png)
You can add the details like this and get/set/update data using the getter setter method in Flutter for Firebase.
In get method you get the unique id for all data you data store that ids, so unique id for all countries, then click use that id to fetch that country's city and so on.

Comment: Thanks for sharing how to do that, now I see first need to update my database.